# Route values could not taking to the values

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, routes

I want to route from one page to another page.

**Candidatesvas**- controller

Here I have code,

```
 [Authorize, HttpPost,HandleErrorWithAjaxFilter]
    public ActionResult Details(FormCollection collection)
    {
        Order order = _repository.GetOrder(LoggedInOrder.Id);
            order.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
            order.Amount = 360;
            order.Validity = 60;
            _repository.Save();


    }
```

when I click Index page,"any link", it saves in db and go to next details page.

**Index.aspx:**

```
<%:Html.actionlink("Details","Details","Candidatesvas")%>
```

like that...

**Global.ascx:**

```
     routes.MapRouteLowercase(
          "SaveVas",
          "details/candidatesvas",
          new { controller = "Candidatesvas", action = "Details" }
      );
```

But when i click link, it shows "resource cannot be found". i changed many way. please help me. i can't find out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller action is decorated with the `[HttPost]` attribute which means that this action is only accessible with the POST verb. Then you have shown some link on your page:

```
<%:Html.ActionLink("Details","Details","Candidatesvas")%>
```

But as you know a link sends GET request. If you want to be able to invoke this action you should either remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute from it or use an HTML `<form>` instead of a link.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%:Html.actionlink("Details","Details","Candidatesvas",null,null)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Html.actionlink for post method.

go for  [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Ajax/jQuery.post&redirect=no)

Or call form submit on click function.